# Font awesome is not working with bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, fonts, font-awesome

I am new in bootstrap

I made a new page and this is my page (there is not content on it!)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang = "fa">

   <head>
   <meta charset = "utf-8">
   <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

      <title>TEST</title>

    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style/index.css">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">



   </head>

   <body>
    <header>
     <div class="container">
        <a class="fa fa-ban">Test ban</a>
     </div>
     </header>






      <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

      <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
      <script src = "//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

   </body>
</html>
```

As you see I have an `<a>` element and it has a `font-awesome` class, I mean `fa fa-ban`, but it is not working!

**What is the problem?**

Comment: check your console for error, put script tag outside body

Comment: @UbiquitousDevelopers There are some warnings, but I don't know why, I just did what bootstrap said, I added some reference to its css files and ... but I don't know what is the problem

Comment: it's working in me. just refresh your page with CTRL+F5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now I found the answer myself.

As you see there is a link to `index.css`, I had a little bad code in my `index.css` that is:

```
*, *:after, *:before{
    box-sizing: inherit;
}

*, * *,{
    /* Set your content font stack here: */
    font-family: 'arad', Times, "Times New Roman", serif !important;
}
```

When I removed that, it is working correctly now!

Comment: Are you sure that was the problem? The css selector has an error, so the whole rule should have been ignored by the browsers.

Comment: @MrLister Yes, that worked for me when I removed those lines. What are my css selector problems? I can't see

Comment: The bottom one starts with `*, * *,{`, which is not correct. The last comma shouldn't be there. So since there is an error in the selector, the browsers ignore the whole style rule. See [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/1t88oku5/) where everything is supposed to be red, but it isn't. (It _does_ work if you remove the last comma.)

Answer (score 3):

This works for me: https://jsfiddle.net/smit_patel/teg7kfc4/

Work fine in by this Tag.

```
<a><i class="fa fa-2x fa-ban"></i>Test ban</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

try use `<i>` tag inside `<a>`

```
<a href="#"><i class="fa fa-ban"></i>Test ban</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot directly use the classes inside `<a>` tag i suspect.

So this

```
<a class="fa fa-ban">Test ban</a>
```

must be replaced with

```
<a href="#"><i class="fa fa-ban"></i>Test ban</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me: https://jsfiddle.net/fka3gp1b/

I would perhaps reformat your code slightly so that the font awesome icon is a child of the anchor element as follows:

```
<a href="#"><i class="fa fa-ban"></i>Test ban</a>
```

Similarly, using a span tag works just as well:

```
<a href="#"><span class="fa fa-ban"></span>Test ban</a>
```